# quote values of helm set in azure pipeline task HelmDeploy@0

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, kubernetes-helm, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to deploy a helm chart that is located in the repo.

```yaml
- task: HelmDeploy@0Chart"
  inputs:
    ...
    overrideValues: |
      foo.bar="$(VAL_A)"
      fiz.faz="$(VAL_B)"
```

The command it puts together looks like this.

```sh
helm upgrade \
  --install 
  --set foo.bar=baz,fiz.faz=with space \ # this whitespace is the culprint
  --wait \
  myapp ./helm-chart/
```

The error I am getting is this.

```
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments

Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
```

I found out that I get the same error locally, when I don't quote the variable with whitespace in the `--set flag`.

```sh
--set foo.bar=baz,fiz.faz=with space
```

I am getting those from a secret injected into the pipeline. How can I ensure they are quoted?

Note, that changing the order of those didn't help. I have also tried to double-double quote the values

```
fiz.faz=""$(VAL_B)""
```

but it seems like all quotes are stripped away.

Answer (score -1):

- Helm upgrade requires both release name and the chart it
  references.Hope you have checked that.
- Some times it may be due to different Helm versions  or
  even when the variables are not referenced properly in the --set flag(Check spellings of variables assigned).
- `overrideValues` field may not accept multiline override variables.

> According to the  [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/helm-deploy?view=azure-devops#install-command), multiple values should be separated
> with commas key1=val1,key2=val2.

Ex:

```
overrideValues : 'foo.bar=$(VAL_A),fiz.faz=$(VAL_B)’
```

For single value

Ex:

```
overrideValues: 'foo.bar=$(value)'
```

You may try using the arguments field and pass the variables as reference 2.

```
arguments: >
          --set foo=bar
          --set foo1=bar1
          --set foo2=bar2
```

Also see [The-format-and-limitations-of-set](https://v2-14-0.helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of-set)

**References:**

1. [file-azure-pipelines-github](https://gist.github.com/jamesrcounts/e6b138e489a2d60ba2204e5344520a94#file-azure-pipelines-complete-yaml-L174)
2. [multiline-overridevalues-helm-SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825295/multiline-overridevalues-helm-install-azure-devops)

Comment: I think you are missing the point of this question

Comment: And your referenced answer is also not true. At least with the current version. If you watch closely at the output of my helm command you can see that it puts comma there automatically when using yaml multiline syntax. The issue is not about multiline. Its about whitespace in the value. The same happens if you run helm locally. You can fix it by quoting the values but I´havent figured out how to get quotes around the values in the pipeline.